# Using ruby timeout in a thread making a database call

Tags: ruby, multithreading, timeout

I am using Ruby 1.9.2.

I have a thread running which makes periodic calls to a database. The calls can be quite long, and sometimes (for various reasons) the DB connection disappears. If it does disappear, the thread just silently hangs there forever.

So, I want to wrap it all in a timeout to handle this. The problem is, on the second time through when a timeout should be called (always second), it still simply hangs. The timeout never takes effect. I know this problem existed in 1.8, but I was lead to believe timeout.rb worked in 1.9.

```
t = Thread.new do
  while true do
    sleep SLEEPTIME
    begin
      Timeout::timeout(TIMEOUTTIME) do
        puts "About to do DB stuff, it will hang here on the second timeout"
        db.do_db_stuff()
        process_db_stuff()
      end
    rescue Timeout::Error
      puts "Timed out"
      #handle stuff here
    end
  end
end
```

Any idea why this is happening and what I can do about it?

Comment: So it's not throwing Timeout::Error? Is it throwing any errors at all?

Comment: Correct, nothing happens, it just freezes right where it is. At least, that's what I've determined from putting excessive `puts` everywhere to determine where/if execution is picked back up.

Comment: Why would that be doing the throwing? The whole point of timeout should be that it raises an error if the block it's given runs for too long. I've tried datamapper and mysql2 directly, hoping either would do an automatic reconnect and solve the problem that way, but no luck. If specifics help, let's say it's a mysql2 connection on which I do a `.query(...)`. Nothing is ever thrown from there, anyways, and a generic `rescue` clause outside it should catch it in any event.

Comment: You're right, excuse me. Putting just a `sleep 30` with `TIMEOUTTIME = 20` inside your `Timeout::timeout` block verified that. I'm not sure. I'll play around with it some more. You might need to add a `break` in the rescue block, maybe, depending on how you're handling it?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to handle it yet - manually reset the db connection will be what I first try, but regardless as a first step I was just seeing that timeout did, in fact, work. I would expect, regardless of what I do or how I handle it, as long as I keep coming back to that timeout block (which I do), timeout would be there to snipe things taking too long, but it seems to work only the once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is that your thread does not hang, it actually **dies**. Here's what you should do to figure out what's going on. Add this before you create your worker thread:

```
Thread.abort_on_exception = true
```

When an exception is raised inside your thread that is never caught, your whole process is terminated, and you can see which exception was raised. Otherwise (and this is the default), your thread is killed.

If this turns out *not* to be the problem, read on...

Ruby's implementation of timeouts is pretty naive. It sets up a separate thread that sleeps for *n* seconds, then blindly raises a Timeout exception inside the original thread.

Now, the original code might actually be in the middle of a `rescue` or `ensure` block. Raising an exception in such a block will silently abort any kind of cleanup code. This might leave the code that times out in an improper state.

It's quite difficult to tell if this is your problem exactly, but seeing how database handlers might do a fair bit of locking and exception handling, it might be very likely. [Here's an article that explains the issue in more depth](http://headius.blogspot.com/2008/02/rubys-threadraise-threadkill-timeoutrb.html).

Is there any way you can use your database library's built-in timeout handling? It might be implemented on a lower level, not using Ruby's timeout implementation.

A simple alternative is to schedule the database calls in a separate process. You can fork the main process each time you do the heavy database-lifting. Or you could set up a simple cronjob to execute a script that executes it. This will be slightly more difficult if you need to communicate with your main thread. Please leave some more details if you want any advice on which option might suit your needs.

---

Based on your comments, the thread is dying. This might be a fault in libraries or application code that you may or may not be able to fix. If you wish to trap any arbitrary error that is generated by the database handling code and subsequently retry, you can try something like the following:

```
t = Thread.new do
  loop do
    sleep INTERVAL
    begin
      # Execute database queries and process data
    rescue StandardError
      # Log error or recover from error situation before retrying
    end
  end
end
```

You can also use the `retry` keyword in the `rescue` block to retry immediately, but you probably should keep a counter to make sure you're not accidentally retrying indefinitely when an unrecoverable error keeps occurring.

Comment: It appears it is indeed dying, though now I don't understand the error I'm getting: `rescue in block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Object::Error (NameError)`

Comment: It appears it is indeed dying, though now I don't understand the error I'm getting: `rescue in block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Object::Error (NameError)`. Regardless of that, though, how can I handle this? The data I get from the db gets coallated and coalesced with other stuff and then services call it, so I'd like to be able to spawn another identical thread if/when this thread dies. Since it always happens _after_ the first timeout, I could also proactively kill the thread in the timeout handler, again, if I could clone the thread elsewhere.

Comment: Good to know! It would be best to find out the cause of this exception and fix it, but it may be enough to catch those exceptions and simply try again. Answer has been updated to explain how.